# Blockchain.info handling gap of 20 unused addresses limit

Tags: address, blockchain.info

I am looking for a way to handle the limitation of Blockchain.info, for which it will stop generating public addresses (or at least watching them) after 20 consecutive of them don't have any transaction.

I thought to initially generate many addresses (over the limit of Blockhain, using the gaps_limit parameter) and then reuse them more times, so that after some time there will not longer be gaps. But I am not sure if Blockchain simply can't watch too long gaps or can only watch 20 addresses at a given time.

Any suggestion? I am also open to other solutions.

Comment: Related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/48090/how-to-solve-blockchain-20-address-gap-limit-problem